# PetaPoco mapping properties within properties

Tags: petapoco

I am new to PetaPoco and initially I was liking it but then hit a wall which I simply dont know how to search for.
I have a object which needs to set a property within one of its properties, ie Job.Min.BaseValue. The source of this data is "min_mb".
So basically my object is not a direct mapping of the source table

```
public class Usage
{
   public Decimal BaseValue {get;set;}
   public Decimal BaseScale {get;set;}
   public Decimal BaseUnit {get;set;} 
}

[PetaPoco.TableName("data")]
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("date, client_name")]
[PetaPoco.ExplicitColumns] 
public class Job
{
   [PetaPoco.Column("date")]
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
   [PetaPoco.Column("client_name")]
   public String ClientName {get;set;}

   public Usage Min {get;set;}

   public CommvaultJob() { Min = new Usage() { BaseScale=1024, BaseUnit="MB" }; }
}
```

Comment: And what it's the structure of the table you are trying to map? Do you have another table?

Comment: No the table is flat, the columns are {client_name, date, min_mb}, there is no join

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the extra type when you call Fetch or Query. This worked for me :

Calling PetaPoco :

```
var allData = _db.Fetch<TestJobPoco,Usage>("select * from dataTEST");
return View( allData);
```

The pocos :

```
[PetaPoco.ExplicitColumns]
public class Usage
{
   public Usage()
   {
       BaseScale=1024;
       BaseUnit="MB";
   }

   [PetaPoco.Column("base_value")]
   public Decimal BaseValue {get;set;}

   [PetaPoco.Ignore]
   public Decimal BaseScale {get;set;}

   [PetaPoco.Ignore]
   public string BaseUnit {get;set;} 
}

[PetaPoco.TableName("dataTEST")]
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("id")]
[PetaPoco.ExplicitColumns]
public class TestJobPoco
{
   [PetaPoco.Column("id")]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   [PetaPoco.Column("date")]
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}

   [PetaPoco.Column("client_name")]
   public String ClientName {get;set;}

   public Usage Min {get;set;}

    public TestJobPoco()
    {
        //Min = new Usage() { BaseScale=1024, BaseUnit="MB" };
    }
}
```

My test database has an id, date, client_name and base_value columns. The primary key is id so it's slightly different than yours but this shouldn't change the way the poco mapping happens.

Answer (score 0):

If your objects do not map with the table structure, an ORM can't help much.

You will need to do the mapping manually or made new shadow properties that copy the values of the other fields, but this added complexity will defeat the purpose of an ORM.

Comment: I should be specific; The data does direct map but not to simple types (int, string, etc). I want to be able to use a column or collection of columns to fill a property. i.e. if I use the Unit class in .NET it has a Unit Type and Value which maybe stored in the database in two separate columns. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: This generally works well if you have a `Unit` table, so you can map the object